# Accessing XML Attributes

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have an XML file with nodes and attributes. I am accessing and receiving data from XML with classic ASP. But XML files has some attributes I should print on the screen.

The XML file is something like

```
<root>
<product>
<node1>Node1 Value</node1>
<node2>Node2 Value</node2>
<attribute value="category">Category Name</attribute>
</product>
</root>
```

And I am receiving the data with this script

```vb
Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
objXMLDoc.async = True
objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath("ProductList3.xml")

Dim xmlProduct
For Each xmlProduct In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("product")

     Dim node1 : node1 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("node1").text
     Dim node2 : node2 = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("node2").text

     Response.Write "<b>node1:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(node1) & "<br> "
     Response.Write "<b>node2:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(node2) & "<br>"   %>
Next
```

I don't have any problem accessing the nodes but i need to get attribute value "category", so i tried something like

```vb
Dim category : Set category = getText(xmlProduct.SelectNodes("root/product/attribute value[@name='category']")
```

But i am receiving `")" required in line 52 error (err no:800a03ee)`.

```vb
Set category= getText(xmlProduct.SelectNodes("root/attribute value[@name='Category']")
```

I must get the category name in the attribute but couldn't find any solution, maybe I am completely wrong in line 52. Can you guys help me to solve the issue?

Comment: There is no node named `urun` in your XML. Please double check that your sample code matches your sample input document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim productList, product, node1, node2, category

Set productList = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
productList.async = False  ' you don't want async document loading on the server
productList.load Server.MapPath("ProductList3.xml")

For Each product In productList.selectNodes("/root/product")
     Set node1 = product.selectSingleNode("./node1")
     Set node2 = product.selectSingleNode("./node2")
     Set category = product.selectSingleNode("./attribute[@value='category']")

     Response.Write "<b>node1:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(node1.text) & "<br>"
     Response.Write "<b>node2:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(node2.text) & "<br>"
     Response.Write "<b>category:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(category.text) & "<br>"
Next
```

Since it's not very smart to select nodes and use their properties without knowing whether that node actually exists (`selectSingleNode` can return `Nothing`, which will lead to run-time errors in the code above), the following is much safer to use:

```vb
For Each product In productList.selectNodes("/root/product")
     node1 = GetText(product, "./node1")
     node2 = GetText(product, "./node2")
     category = GetText(product, "./attribute[@value='category']")

     Response.Write "<b>node1:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(node1) & "<br>"
     Response.Write "<b>node2:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(node2) & "<br>"
     Response.Write "<b>category:</b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(category) & "<br>"
Next

Function GetText(context, xpath)
    Dim node
    GetText = ""
    If Not context Is Nothing And xpath > "" Then
        Set node = context.selectSingleNode(xpath)
        If Not node Is Nothing Then GetText = node.text
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. Edited the text i hope that will help others a lot.

Comment: unfortunatelly, there's a "ç" letter in one of the attribute. Is there any way to get data from this attribute : <ozellik tanim="Açıklama">Content </ozellik>

Comment: @Serhat The code above can read all characters, don't change it. What happens to the `ç` character in your case?

Comment: Its just not writing the content of the attribute. I confirmed it by find & replace "çık" with "cik" in <ozellik tanim="Açıklama"> then it worked fine.

Comment: but i have to fix it because the code will be useless to work with if i have to do the replace everytime i update the XML file.

Comment: As I said, my code above has no errors. Either your XML is using the wrong encoding or your ASP output is using the wrong encoding, or your server sends the wrong Content-Type header. First ensure that your XML file is encoded as UTF-8. Then set `Response.CodePage = 65001` and `Response.Charset = "UTF-8"` in ASP. Cross-check that your browser actually selects `UTF-8` as the page encoding.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i wasnt arround for a while. Tried @Tomalak 's suggestions and some other searching results but no chance. I am not able to get the values from the attributes containing ç, ş, ö, ü, ı letters in their name.. Not the attribute value, the name of the attribute.. Still searchig for a solution. There's no change the source XML values since its shared by others..

Comment: I have made several suggestions in my comment above. Did you go through them? Your error description is basically "it doesn't work", that is much too vague.

Comment: i agree with you it seems vague but there's no error message. :) .Its always simplier with an error message so you know whats going on but my case is a little bit sick :) Checked the XML is encoded UTF-8. Tried with `<%response.codepage= 65001%>`  `<%response.charset="utf-8"%>`it prints the Turkish charachters broken as _AÃ§Ä±klama:_ (there supposed to be the content of `<ozellik tanim="Açıklama">Content</ozellik>` after the _:_

Comment: Did you check that the browser selects the correct page encoding? What happens if you select UTF-8 in the browser manually?